# Why is the DataGridView columns stacked on top of each other?

Tags: .net, datagridview, delphi-prism, datagridviewcolumn, oxygene

On a winform, I have a DataGridView and columns within it. For some odd reason, when I run my program, the columns are stacked on top of each other during runtime. No matter what I do, it won't change. I don't know if I am setting certain properties or what.

**During design time:**

[image]

**During run time:**

[image]

Comment: Check the column widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by lc, columns width and minimum width needs to be set. I had my column's width to 100 and minimum width to 5. When I changed the minimum width to 100, it worked.

Thanks lc.